# how to get the id from the dropdown list

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I created a web app that can add a masseur and assign its schedule and show the schedule details. [Adding and showing Masseur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcgeN.png)
[Displaying the schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkfzR.png)
[Adding a sched page[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq7VV.png)

When i add a masseur the will be saved in the phpmyadmin tbl_masseur.
When i add a schedule to the masseur the dropdown list shows masseur firstname from the tbl_masseur
when i add schedule to the masseur Date Start :Date End Time Start  Time End It will saved in tbl_sched

Time End:
[tbl_masseur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfCKQ.png)
[tbl_sched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfTQ0.png)

1. Is it possible to get personid from the dropdown list when I click "submit" button.
2. How can I get the personid from the tbl_masseur and copy its data to the tbl_sched when I click Submit in adding a schedule page.

ps. sorry for wrong grammar. Thank you

```
<?php

        include('conn.php');
        
        $sql = ("SELECT mass_fname FROM tbl_masseur");
        

        $result =mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        echo "<select name='person'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            
            echo "<option value='".$row['mass_fname']."'>".$row['mass_fname']."</option>"; 
        }
        echo "</select>";

        ?>
```

This is my dropdown code

Comment: Show us your dropdown code

Comment: _SIde note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL databases. Your application is connecting directly to MySQL and has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin.